# Ошибка транзакции postgresql

Tags: python, база-данных, postgresql, aiogram, бот

При удалении строки из таблицы возникает следующия ошибка. Делаю телеграм бота с помощью aiogram, psycopg2

psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

вот часть кода, в которой возникает постоянно ошибка:

**sqlite_db.py**

```
import os
from create_bot import bot
import psycopg2 as ps


base = ps.connect(os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL'), sslmode='require')
cur = base.cursor()

async def sql_delete_command(data):
    cur.execute('DELETE FROM menu WHERE name == %s', (data,))
    base.commit()
```

**admin.py**

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda x: x.data and x.data.startswith('del'))
async def del_callback_run(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await sqlite_db.sql_delete_command(callback_query.data.replace('del ', ''))
    await callback_query.answer(text=f'{callback_query.data.replace("del ", "")} удалена.', show_alert=True)

@dp.message_handler(commands='Удалить')
async def delete_item(message: types.Message):
    if message.from_user.id == ID:
        read = await sqlite_db.sql_read2()
        for ret in read:
            await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, ret[0], f'{ret[1]}\nОписание: {ret[2]}\nЦена {ret[-1]}')
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text='^^^', reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup().\
                add(InlineKeyboardButton(f'Удалить {ret[1]}', callback_data=f'del {ret[1]}')))
```

задеплоил бота на бесплатный сервер heroku. Я впервые делаю бота

Comment: А почему равно двойное в delete

Comment: Разве проверка на равенство не так проверяется? например if 7 == 7: return True

Comment: Еще интересно откуда у вас в функции sql_delete_command берутся переменные cur и base. И почему функция асинхронная, а обращение к базе синхронное (т.е. у вас фактически и вся функция синхронная выходит)

Comment: это в питоне ==, а вы описание языка sql почитайте, никакого двойного равно там нет

Comment: Я могу на github залить полный, сечайс средактирую код

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло